# Mann-Whitney-U-Test as a replacement for Chow-Test?

Tags: regression, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, chow-test

The Chow-Test tests if there is a significant difference between a pair of regression equations under the null hypothesis the two models are equivalent.

My idea is to use the Mann-Whitney-U-Test to test for difference of regression equations.
The latter test tests if the residuals are from different populations under the null hypothesis that they are from the same population. Hence, my assumption is that if the residuals differ than the regression equations differ, too. Is this correct? Why should anyone bother to use the chow-test instead?

Comment: State the hypothesis of interest concretely.  Seems like an indirect analysis.

Comment: Are these two models of the same form fitted to different data sets or models of different form fitted to the same data set? (Given the mention of the Chow test, I assume the first, but I thought it best to make certain.)

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your question, I don't think this will work.

Imagine the models are both appropriate. Then the residuals will be centered at 0; no matter how different the equations are there's not likely to be differences in the location of residuals.